# Speech Recognition using Microsoft SAPI 5.4: how to get word duration ?

Tags: windows, exception, speech-recognition, sapi

I am developing a Speech Recognition application using Microsoft SAPI 5.4, in C#. I am using VS 2012 Express under Windows 7.

I want to get the duration of recognized words in an audio file.
I use the follwing code to iterate though recognized words:

```
    void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Result != null) {
            foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words) {
                try {
                    RecognizedAudio audio = e.Result.GetAudioForWordRange(word, word);
                    TimeSpan wordDuration = audio.Duration;
                    Console.WriteLine(word.Text + ": "  + wordDuration.ToString(@"s\.ff");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

It works somehow, but I get the duration of only the first few words of each sentence. The other ones generate a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in System.Speech.dll.

However, if I look at the words (private) members in the debugger, they all have a correct duration.

What's going wrong ?

Comment: Well, sounds like a bug.  I'd postulate that the data is changing while your code loops.  The advantage of using a debugger is that it will freeze the app and not allow more recognition to take place.  Do try this in a Winforms app so the thread has the correct apartment state, that always matters for a COM api like this one.  You can file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com, don't expect miracles.

Comment: @Hans The code I mention is already inside a Winform.